# Adding couple of conditions to existing Shell script

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I am a total newbie on Shell scripting. Current, I have an existing script to which I have been asked to do the following:

1. Before anything gets executed from the script, check the DB connection.
2. If DB connection is successful, proceed normally.
3. If DB connection is unsuccessful, then mail the admin stating failed DB connection and quit, without running anything from the script.

The script below is what I currently have. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
source ~/.bashrc
# Needed by SQL*Plus on DEV
# Old DEV - ORACLE_HOME=/app/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/client_1 ; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/client_1 ; export ORACLE_HOME
SQL_CMD=/app/oracle/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/client_1/bin/sqlplus
```

```
# Specify the location of the final file
OUTDIR=/app/tableauTomcat/webapps/docs
OUTFILE=/app/tableauTomcat/webapps/docs/provider_list.json
PROVFILE=provider_list.json

# Development Credentials
CREDS=SOMEUSERNAME/SOMEPASSWORD@dev.clo0fiz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/dev

DATE=`date +%Y%m%d_%H_%M`
BASE_DIR=${OUTDIR}
if [ -f $BASE_DIR/$PROVFILE ]; then
    cp $BASE_DIR/$PROVFILE $BASE_DIR/$PROVFILE.$DATE
    /usr/bin/gzip $BASE_DIR/$PROVFILE.$DATE
fi

# Find and remove any files older than 3 days
find $BASE_DIR -name "${PROVFILE}.*" -a -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;

echo ${OUTFILE}
echo ${ORACLE_HOME}
echo ${SQL_CMD}
echo ${PATH}

echo -n "Starting p_provider_timeline procedure:  "
date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'

${SQL_CMD} /nolog << EOF0
CONNECT ${CREDS}
exec p_provider_timeline;
```

Comment: What do you think where in your script those conditions should go?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get output status of sqlplus command from shell/shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564994/how-to-get-output-status-of-sqlplus-command-from-shell-shell-script)

Comment: I believe the condition must be just below the CREDS line. CREDS is where I am defining the DB connection settings.